# How can I create or rebind a Power BI Report using XMLA Endpoint and C#?

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have gone through the [Learning TOM tutorial at this link](https://github.com/PowerBiDevCamp/Tabular-Object-Model-Tutorial/blob/main/Solution/Exercise04/PBI-Tool/Program.cs) and have been able to successfully create a Power BI Dataset online using XMLA Endpoint and C#.

However, one point I am stuck at right now is creating a simple blank report to go with the dataset.  I don't want any visuals on the report but I want something since I will be embedding these reports for end users to customize as they please.

I've gone through these links to find a starting point but haven't come across anything yet.  This is my first attempt at doing anything with XMLA and C# but I have managed to make a lot of progress with the dataset.

https://github.com/PowerBiDevCamp/Tabular-Object-Model-Tutorial/blob/main/Solution/Exercise04/PBI-Tool/Program.cs

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/power-bi-meets-programmability-tom-xmla-and-c

https://www.powerbidevcamp.net/articles/programming-datasets-with-TOM/

Has anyone done something like this in the past?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to do this via XMLA Endpoint, however I was able to do this via REST API's.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clone-report?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main()
    {
        var url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/TENANT_ID/Clone";
        var data = "{\r\n  \"name\": \"REPORT NAME\",\r\n  \"targetModelId\": \"DATASET_ID\",\r\n  \"targetWorkspaceId\": \"WORKSPACE_ID\"\r\n}";

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer BEARER_TOKEN");

        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }
}
```